# When to do collision detection? I got very low fps, I think I misuse the detection

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, collision, ogre, bulletphysics

I am now learning Ogre for 3D programming.

In my scene, there are only three entities now, a sphere, a mouse and a cat. the cat is running on the sphere.

As my scene is very simple, I use simple "Minimal Collision Detection"(http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=80829), the performance is ok according to its instruction.

Before I use collision detection, the fps is 60(max as default), after I use it, the fps drops to 13-15.
I use it before each frame was rendered.

```
bool GeneratorFrameListener::frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt){
    Ogre::SceneNode::ChildNodeIterator it = RootSceneNode->getChild("planetSphere")->getChildIterator();
    while(it.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Ogre::Vector3 oldPosition = it.current()->second->getPosition();
        it.current()->second->setPosition( oldPosition*0.98 );

        Collision::SCheckCollisionAnswer ret = collision_tools->check_ray_collision(oldPosition, it.current()->second->getPosition(),0.4F);
        if (ret.collided)
        {
            it.current()->second->setPosition(oldPosition);
        }
        it.getNext();
    }
    //other code like listen the keyboard
}
```

At the begin I thought the objects need to fall down on sphere first. so before each frame, I detect whether object is collided with something(collision between cat and mouse I did in movement function, so I assume if collison here, it would be the object and the sphere.)

I wonder whether it is too expensive to do collision detection before each frame, Is there a better solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: My experience with collision detection (and certainly this library) is limited, but I have two suggestions to consider. First, I would check to ensure you really only have the number of nodes you are expecting. If you somehow gained more, that might not be obvious from what you posted. Second, the complexity of an object geometry can really increase the time for collision detection if it is done on a face basis (rather than bounding box). You might want to look at object complexity and see if simpler objects give better performance.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do collisions is to move your entities, then use "bounding box" (or sphere, or cylinder) to determine if they might overlap, then use more precise and much more expensive tests (e.g. polygon/mesh intersection) if and only if you've already determined it's necessary for that specific pair of entities.

The correct way to do collisions is quite different. What you really want to do is keep a "movement vector" for each entity (e.g. "entity #2 started moving in direction X and a speed of Y at time T") and calculate the instant that it would collide with something else when you set the movement vector; so that you're not doing collision detection every single game tick and you can accurately handle the case where 2 entities collide in between frames. *Note: Have you ever seen games where fast moving objects "pass through" other objects without colliding? This is because the entities aren't overlapping in the frame before the collision, and aren't overlapping in the frame after the collision.*

Also; real people are not "unintelligent" - they don't set a course and go until they hit something, then set a new course and go until they hit the next thing, etc. Instead real people use prediction - they'll realise that if they keep going they will collide with something and alter their speed or direction to avoid the collision before it occurs. This is relatively easy to do if you use the "movement vector" approach; and **it's impossible to have a realistic simulation of intelligent entities if you use the "test for overlap every game tick" approach**. It also means that if you use the "movement vector" approach you avoid most collisions based on results from the "bounding box/sphere/cylinder" tests, and avoid almost all of the very expensive "polygon/mesh intersection" tests.

Of course doing it correctly takes some impressive/complex maths skills (it means doing collision detection in 4 dimensions instead of in 3 dimensions); so almost all game developers use the broken/dodgy "test for overlap every game tick" approach.